# Restricting number of jobs run per time period

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have an application that queues requests received from callers. Each request results in a call to an external web service that has restrictions on how many calls we can make to it. E.g. we can only make X calls per minute.

Each request is added to Quartz.NET scheduler and I need to be able to schedule jobs in such a way as to not violate the terms of the external web service.

I've considered keeping track somehow of the last time a job was added to scheduler and making sure jobs are triggered N milliseconds apart (i.e. each job coming in is set to trigger at LastJobTime + N), where N = (60000/X). However, I'm not sure if this is reasonable.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? If not, must I keep track of LastJobTime myself or can Quartz.NET provide some help here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [TriggerListener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html) that implements the `ITriggerListener` interface. The `ITriggerListener` give you the possibility to veto a job. Just count how many calls do you made in this minute and if you over your call contingent, veto the Job.